# MVVMCross and Zumero Sync

Tags: c#, cross-platform, xamarin, mvvmcross, zumero

Has anyone tried to use Zumero Client with the MvvmCross Sqlite plugin?

The client libraries currently provided do not support portable class libraries. "Yes" I know we can create one by using a different BinaryFormatter (i.e. UniversalSerializer) but want to know before I take on the endeavor of create an MvvmCross Plugin for the Zumero Client.

Answer (score 0):

Go here[a http://zumero.com/dev-center/zss/#zssclientsdk]
Download sdk and there is cordova or phonegap sample you can use zumero sync function for Zumero Client with the MvvmCross Sqlite plugin

```
  zumero.sync("/data/data/com.example.myapp/mydb",
   "",
   "https://zss.example.com",
   "mydb",
   '{"scheme_type":"table", "table":"users"}',
   "user",
   "password",
   function() {
      // success
   },
   function(result) {
      // failure - result.code and result.message will
      // contain details
   }
);
```